# SQL getting name from userform

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am having a little trouble with my SQL in access

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO _tbl_Structure " & _
            "SELECT * " & _
            "FROM [MS Access;pwd=" & strPassword & ";database=" & DBpath & "\" & DBname & "].[" & tblStructure & "] " & _
            "WHERE [user] = '" & [Forms!frm_Advisors_Stats-manager].[Position]
```

The issue appears to be with

> [Forms!frm_Advisors_Stats-manager].[Position]

Any help on what I am doing wrong here?

The position textbox shows if the person logged in is a manager or not. If they are a manager as stated on the userform is pulls all records the manager has on the team

The error shown is:

> External name not defined

Comment: You are not closing the quote in `= '" & [Forms!frm_Advisors_Stats-manager].[Position]` . Should be `= '" & [Forms!frm_Advisors_Stats-manager].[Position] & "'"`

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after I posted, I have closed it off but getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use correct bracketing:

```
[Forms]![frm_Advisors_Stats-manager]![Position]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using string concatenation, your object notation needs to be valid for VBA. Since your object name contains a hyphen, you need to properly refer to it using the forms collection and without the bang operator.

```
"WHERE [user] = '" & Forms("frm_Advisors_Stats-manager").Position.Value & "'"
```

Comment: Thank you - This has thrown out another error: Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: That sounds like you're either misspelling the form or form control name, or the form is not open.

Comment: Just before the code runs I have this line:         DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Advisors_Stats-manager", acNormal

The code is also in a module would this impact it

Comment: That doesn't prove you're not misspelling the form control name, but wouldn't influence it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to reference a control on a form that I used a lot is:

```
Form_Advisors_Stats-manager.Position
```

Therefore:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO _tbl_Structure " & _
        "SELECT * " & _
        "FROM [MS Access;pwd=" & strPassword & ";database=" & DBpath & "\" & DBname & "].[" & tblStructure & "] " & _
        "WHERE [user] = '" & Form_Advisors_Stats-manager.Position & "'"
```